# Changing Chrome's User Agent?

Tags: development, google-chrome, web-browsing

Is it possible to change Chrome (or Chrome based browsers) user agents on OSX? I dont see a menu or preference option for doing so.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This [link](http://moi.cirne.com/index.php/2009/12/19/setting-user-agent-for-mac-chrome/) shows how to do it using Terminal. The Terminal command that opens Chrome using the Safari user agent string:

```
open /Applications/Google\ Chrome.app   --args -user-agent="Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; U; Intel Mac OS X 10_5_3; en-us) AppleWebKit/525.19 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/3.2.1 Safari/525.19"
```

I tested this, and it works with the current version of Chrome. You can find various User-Agent strings [here](http://www.useragentstring.com/pages/useragentstring.php).

Comment: @Kevin: You're welcome. Please feel free to mark this question as answered.

Answer (score 0):

## [ScriptNo](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/oiigbmnaadbkfbmpbfijlflahbdbdgdf)

[image]

...is an extension for Google Chrome which brings some of Firefox's NoScript extension functionality in a user-friendly fashion to Chrome.

It also features the ability of **user-agent spoofing**.

[image]